# Responsive <picture> images with fallback

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive-images

I'm trying to use the `<picture>` element to provide 3 different images: 1 for mobile, 1 for `min-width: 768px`, and 1 for IE as a fallback.

```
<picture>
  <source class="article-bg-image" media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="tablet-desktop.jpg" alt="Text" title="Text">
  <img class="img-responsive" srcset="mobile.jpg" alt="Text" title="Text">
</picture>
```

This works as expected on mobile vs. desktop, but I don't want the mobile image to be used as a fallback on IE. How would I specifically provide an image for mobile? I tried a second `source` with no `media` attribute, but it wasn't used.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

You can try this way

```html
  <img src="mobile.jpg" class="img-responsive" srcset="large.png 1280w,medium.png 640w, small.png 320w" sizes="100%" alt="Text" title="Text">
```